# Can I use my retropie as a raspberry pie?

Tags: pi-3, retropie

I have a raspberry pie 3, last year I installed a emulator station to use as a retropie. However I would like to use it as a normal computer now. Is it possible ? When I quit de emulator I'm not able to go on the 'normal' desktop and use any internet page.
thanks!

Comment: Grab a copy of plain Raspbian Buster from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest, grab a copy of Balena Etcher from https://www.balena.io/etcher/. Use Etcher to re-write your SDCard with the fresh copy of Buster. Boot your RPi then keep calm and carry on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to uninstall?

```
sudo ./retropie_setup.sh
```

Option 'x' to [Uninstall RetroPie](https://retropie.org.uk/docs/Manual-Installation/)